# (Fullcalendar 4 VueJS) - Row time format from AM/PM to 24H

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I use `Fullcalendar` component for `VueJs`. I need to setup `24hours` format for all, for events and rows title.

For events I found how to do that:

```
:eventTimeFormat="{
   hour: '2-digit',
   minute: '2-digit',
   hour12: false
}"
```

But for row title I can't.

[image]

Please give your advice.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat

Comment: I added new prop :
:slotLabelFormat="[
    {hour12: false}
],
 but nothing changed.

Comment: I need to figure out what should i pass into "slotLabelFormat" prop to fix my issue

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use the [slotLabelFormat](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat) option.

For example, this will produce an hours/minutes display in 24hr format, like `23:45` etc:

```
:slotLabelFormat="{ 'hour12': false, 'hour': '2-digit', 'minute': '2-digit'}"
```